# Updating qiskit doesn't update qiskit version from Spyder

Tags: qiskit, programming

I installed `qiskit` using directions at `https://qiskit.org/documentation/install.html`
I also have `spyder` installed -`Spyder 3.3.6 | Python 3.7.7 64-bit | Qt 5.9.6 | PyQt5 5.9.2 | Windows 10`

It works fine i.e. I am able to build from `spyder` and connect to `ibm_q` hardware ...
when I run `qiskit.__qiskit_version__` it was

```
{'qiskit-terra': '0.12.0',
 'qiskit-aer': '0.4.1',
 'qiskit-ignis': '0.2.0',
 'qiskit-ibmq-provider': '0.5.0',
 'qiskit-aqua': '0.6.5',
 'qiskit': '0.16.2'}
```

Then I had to update `qiskit to 0.18`

so I went to Conda prompt and did `pip install qiskit`
the installation went through successfully - if I do `conda list` I see the following

```
:
qiskit                    0.18.0                   pypi_0    pypi
qiskit-aer                0.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
qiskit-aqua               0.6.5                    pypi_0    pypi
qiskit-ibmq-provider      0.6.0                    pypi_0    pypi
qiskit-ignis              0.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
qiskit-terra              0.13.0                   pypi_0    pypi
:
```

I then did a reset of `spyder` - inspite of that from the `IPython console` I still see the older version - `'qiskit': '0.16.2'`

I ran `print( qiskit.__qiskit_version__)` in my script that runs inside Spyder I still see '`qiskit': '0.16.2'` - please help what else needs to be done. What am I missing here? Thank you

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing to do with quantum computing. It should be asked on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Previously I had run the `pip install qiskit --upgrade` in the ***wrong conda environment***.

So here is how I fixed it

```
conda activate <to_the_environment_that_Spyder_uses>
```

then run `pip install qiskit --upgrade`

After successful update completion - verify using `conda list`
here is what i see now

```
:
qiskit                    0.18.0                   pypi_0    pypi
qiskit-aer                0.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
qiskit-aqua               0.6.5                    pypi_0    pypi
qiskit-ibmq-provider      0.6.0                    pypi_0    pypi
qiskit-ignis              0.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
qiskit-terra              0.13.0                   pypi_0    pypi
:
```

From inside the spyder script - for  `print( qiskit.__qiskit_version__)`
I see

```
{'qiskit-terra': '0.13.0', 'qiskit-aer': '0.5.0', 'qiskit-ignis': '0.3.0', 'qiskit-ibmq-provider': '0.6.0', 'qiskit-aqua': '0.6.5', 'qiskit': '0.18.0'}
```

from the IPython console, I get `...'qiskit': '0.18.0'}` too